# Creating a PNG or PDF from railroady

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, svg, uml, erd

I just started using the [railroady gem](https://github.com/preston/railroady). but I cant seem to be able to get a PNG or a PDF file

I am able to run the `rake diagram:all` and I get my SVG file in the ./doc/ directory but I am not sure how to convert them to a PNG or a SVG

I see thin the documentation `railroady -C | neato -Tpng > controllers.png` but I am not sure how to apply this.

from the root of my project this just create a file called **controllers.png*& but its empty

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do exactly that

```
railroady -M | neato -Tpng > ./doc/models.png
```

to create a the uml for the model in the doc directory